# Error when trying sudo apt upgrade or install

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, plymouth

I'm a new Ubuntu 16.04 user. It was working nicely, then whenever I tried to install new software or to upgrade, I received an error message. I tried to go through the suggestion posted for the same error, but it failed. Every time I received the same error.

Error message:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 procps
 apport
 bluez
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is the last command that I tried with the resulting error:

```
marwa@marwa-Inspiron-5567[marwa] sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The image is a screenshot of the last lines of the error message.

[image]

Comment: Answered: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/284708

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when packages are broken or not fully upgrade.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/*
sudo apt update
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg configure-a
```

Try the commands above.

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried the first command and i received this message: sudo: unable to execute /bin/rm: Argument list too long
zsh: hangup     sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/*

Comment: I tried to skip the first one and run sudo apt update and it gave me: All packages are up to date.
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55 (five lines). and then sudo apt autoremove :  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 procps
 apport
 bluez

Comment: Try those commands from root user.